# Javascript how do I give a variable the value of my button dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html, variables, url, button

I'm trying to create a filter to see what shoe's fit people the best.
I'm creating multiple questions and every time I press a button I want the value of that button to be added to my url variable.
I can't seem to figure out how get the value of the button I press and add it to the url variable with an & between values. Can anybody help me?

```js
var Test = [
  [
    'Whats your size?', ['41', 'url1'],
    ['42', 'url2'],
    ['43', 'url3']
  ],
  [
    'What color would you like?', ['Red', 'url1'],
    ['Blue', 'url2'],
    ['Yellow', 'url3'],
    ['Green', 'url4']
  ],
  [
    'What brand would you like?', ['Adidas', 'url1'],
    ['Nike', 'url2'],
    ['Puma', 'url3']
  ]
];

var url = '#';

count = 1;
var questionNumber = 0;
var button = document.getElementById('answer');
var question = document.getElementById('question');
var answerButton;

function check() {
  //question 
  console.log(Test[questionNumber][0]);
  for (let y = 1; y < Test[questionNumber].length; y++) {
    // url
    url = url + Test[questionNumber][y][1];
    // button
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.value = Test[questionNumber][y][1];
    btn.className = "filter_anwser";
    btn.textContent = Test[questionNumber][y][0];
    btn.setAttribute('data-el', 1);
    button.appendChild(btn);
    // class
    answerButton = document.querySelectorAll('.filter_anwser');
    // console.log(url);
  }

  // question
  var txt = document.createElement('h1');
  txt.textContent = Test[questionNumber][0];
  question.appendChild(txt);

  console.log(".....");
  // adds 1 to question to see a different question
  questionNumber++;
}
```

```html
<div id="question"></div>

<div id="answer"></div>

<button onclick="check()">Next</button>
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working? What have you tried to make it work? Could it be a problem that `answerButton` might be overwritten in each iteration of that `for` loop?

Comment: The main problem I have is that I can't figure out how to add the value of the button I pressed to the variable. I've tried to do this with an eventlistener, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push and later generate the URL from the object

I would personally use size, brand etc instead of url1, url1,

```
function getLink(parms) {
  return "https://wwww.yourserver.com/shoes#"+parms.join(",")
};

button.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  parms.push(tgt.value);
  console.log(getLink(parms))
})
```

```js
var Test = [
  [
    'Whats your size?', ['41', 'url1'],
    ['42', 'url2'],
    ['43', 'url3']
  ],
  [
    'What color would you like?', ['Red', 'url1'],
    ['Blue', 'url2'],
    ['Yellow', 'url3'],
    ['Green', 'url4']
  ],
  [
    'What brand would you like?', ['Adidas', 'url1'],
    ['Nike', 'url2'],
    ['Puma', 'url3']
  ]
];

// let parms = {};
let parms = []

count = 1;
var questionNumber = 0;
var button = document.getElementById('answer');
var question = document.getElementById('question');
var answerButton;
function getLink(parms) {
/*  const url = new URL("https://wwww.yourserver.com/shoes");
  for (let key in parms) {
    url.searchParams.append(key,parms[key])
  }
  return url.toString()
  */  
  return "https://wwww.yourserver.com/shoes#"+parms.join(",")
};

button.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  //parms[tgt.value] = tgt.textContent;
  parms.push(tgt.value);
  console.log(getLink(parms))
})

function check() {
  //question 
  // console.log(Test[questionNumber][0]);
  for (let y = 1; y < Test[questionNumber].length; y++) {
    // button
    var btn = document.createElement('button');
    btn.value = Test[questionNumber][y][1];
    btn.className = "filter_anwser";
    btn.textContent = Test[questionNumber][y][0];
    btn.setAttribute('data-el', 1);
    button.appendChild(btn);
    // class
    answerButton = document.querySelectorAll('.filter_anwser');
    // console.log(url);
  }

  // question
  var txt = document.createElement('h1');
  txt.textContent = Test[questionNumber][0];
  question.appendChild(txt);
  // adds 1 to question to see a different question
  questionNumber++;
}
```

```html
<div id="question"></div>

<div id="answer"></div>

<button onclick="check()">Next</button>
```

---

Old answer

```
let parms = {};

function getLink(parms) {
  const url = new URL("https://wwww.yourserver.com/product");
  for (let key in parms) {
    url.searchParams.append(key,parms[key])
  }
  return url.toString()
};


button.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
  const tgt = e.target;
  parms[tgt.value] = tgt.textContent;
  console.log(getLink(parms))
})
```

Comment: Thanks alot! I only have one question. It shows the variable like this:                  [{"url3":"43"},{"url1":"Red"},{"url3":"Puma"}]                                                                            but i need to make an actual link of it. I guess this is because it's in an array. Is there a way to make it look like this:                                                                                                  url3&url1&url3?

Comment: Yes. but don't you want `?size=41&brand=Adidas`?

Comment: I do, but I will change the urls. This is just a test project before I implement it in my real one.

Comment: I have updated to use an object and added a getLink

Comment: Thank you! but for some reason the link starts with a ? but i need it to start with http://www.filtertest.com/shoes# but the shoes# comes after all the urls and the ? is still there. also is there a way to get rid of the =42 and only show url2? Sorry I only just started javascript and it took a week to write what I already had so I'm not very good at it.

Comment: Why would you use the hash for the parameters?

Comment: See update. I recommend you do what I did first, so I left the code in there

Comment: Well I'm using it because the links i need to use already exist and I can't change them, so I need to use it. But the new one works perfectly thanks!